# Find a user using a form with PHP backend

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if a user exists on the database using a form front end.
If the user is there don't add to the database.

The code isn't working when adding a user it gives me the user has been added even the user exists.

Here my code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpasswd"); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("ldap", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$netid = $_POST['netid'];
$univid = $_POST['univid'];
if($netid !=''||$univid !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM user ( UserName, temppass WHERE UserName=$netid");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)

{
    echo"NetID $netid already exists";
   }
 else
    {
   //insert query goes here
   $query = mysql_query("insert into user( UserName, temppass ) values ('$netid', '$univid')");
    }

echo "<br/><br/><span>User Registered successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Registration Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
?>
```

Comment: your selct Querru is not proper use Select * from use

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(UserName) as total FROM user;");
```

Then

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

The count of users will be in $result['total']. As an aside the mysql_* methods are inferior to prepared statements (google it).

Comment: Assuming you have a primary key in the user table, that would also be a good candidate to go into the COUNT() bit.

Comment: what is wrong with mine code? Byfleet even if I use your lines where the forms should get the username.

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` query has many errors with it.

```
SELECT FROM user ( UserName, temppass WHERE UserName=$netid
```

First issue you aren't selecting anything. Second issue I don't know what `( UserName, temppass` is, maybe the columns you want to select? Third issue is that `Username` is presumably a string, not an integer, so that value should be in quotes. Once you quote that though you will open yourself to SQL injections.

Here is a valid version of your current query.

```
SELECT UserName, temppass FROM user WHERE UserName='$netid'
```

Here's the doc on mysql's `select`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Here are some links to read up on about SQL injections:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

You also shouldn't be using the `mysql_` functions they are deprecated and insecure now. [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Additional issues:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
```

The `$sql` isn't defined.

I don't know what `$_POST['netid']` is but that sounds like an `id`, not a username.

You shouldn't store passwords in plain text.

You should enable error reporting and/or monitor your error logs.

Comment: I replace the query, but I still cannot get it to work. My form still failing to check if the user already exists.